# Is it possible to visualize cpu usage per thread using JFR and JMC (JDK Mission Control)?

Tags: java, jmc, jfr

I've started dabbling with the JFR + JMC combo which is frankly awesome (great work Hirt & co).

One metric that I'd like to monitor is the cpu usage per thread but I've yet to find out if it's stored anywhere. There are the usual graphs for CPU%, but I'd like to see a similar one broken up into individual threads.

If I connect to a running instance with JMX the stat is available under the threads tab, but I fail to find it for a recorded JFR run.
Is that something that already exists or would be easy to implement on my own?

Answer (score 4):

Just realized you can create your own custom pages based on arbitrary events.

So from `Event browser`select the `thread cpu load`, right click the event name and select `create a new page using the selected event types` and in that page simply right click and `Show in bar chart -> User mode cpu load -> Average user mode CPU load`. Then right click the chart and `Group by -> Event thread`.

To get more samples to plot you will need to create a new profiling setting, bumping the `Thread CPU load` event sampling period to whatever makes sense (like 1s or similar).

Comment: there is no `thread cpu load` in the event types tree. jmc 8.0.0.