# JVisualVM to run scripts when CPU reached 100%

Tags: java, profiling, jvisualvm

using JVisualVM 2.0.5 I found an instance where the CPU usage of my application reached 100%. Is there a way for me to run scripts to check what happened during this time (01:00:13PM). I checked my logs and nothing significant happened. I'm planning to run a thread dump during this point before CPU goes back to normal. Or is there a better way to manage this or plugins?

[image]

Comment: "check what happened" What information do you want?

Comment: essentially I'd like to run some linux scripts like thread dump and perform analysis.

or ps ax --forest -H -j u to check for top running processes by memory and CPU usage

or top -n 1 -H -p 247 to monitor eclipse processes

Once I get those information, I might be able to determine the root cause. Essentially I just need a trigger from JVisualVM when it hit's 100% CPU usage and react to that by running a few scripts, dump the results to a file that I can check later.

Answer (score 1):

No, jvisualvm doesn't provide that kind of monitoring feature. You need to create your own script or application to monitor when the process is using too much CPU (for given values of too much) and execute something else to capture information.

Another option would be to use a different tool like Java Flight Recorder which may be able to capture thread usage over time without any special script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61006913/721855

Comment: appreciate the suggestion. thanks mate.